# Need help understanding this Perl snippet

Tags: perl

I'm reading Learning Perl (6th edition) and came upon a code snippet that I couldn't decipher. One of the exercises after chapter 14 asks to build a program that takes as input a string and a substring then finds the indices at which the substring occurs in the string.

Here's the way I did it:

```
print "Enter a string: ";
chomp($string = <STDIN>);

print "Enter a substring: ";
chomp($sub = <STDIN>);

until ($index == -1) {
  print $index, "\n" if defined($index);
  $index = index($string, $sub, $index + 1);
}
```

In the answers section, they show two ways. One is easy to understand and similar to mine, but the other is purposefully obfuscating:

```
print "Enter a string: ";
chomp($string = <STDIN>);

print "Enter a substring: ";
chomp($sub = <STDIN>);  

for (my $pos = –1; –1 !=
  ($pos = index
    +$string,
    +$sub,
    +$pos
    +1
  );
push @places, ((((+$pos))))) {
  'for ($pos != 1; # ;$pos++) {
     print "position $pos\n";#;';#' } pop @places;
}

print "Locations of '$sub' in '$string' were: @places\n";
```

I have almost no idea what's going on in that for loop. I know it's of the form `for (initialize; test; increment)` and that it's testing that the index is not -1, which means no more occurrences of the substring. But what's going on with the assignment to $pos? Why are there so many parentheses around +$pos? What's going on after the many parentheses? I'd really appreciate it if someone could walk me through the second part. Please keep in mind I've just started learning Perl a week ago.

BTW, I tried running their code but it gave me this error:

```
Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after my $pos = <-- HERE near column 16 at ex14.obfs.pl line 1.
```

Comment: The syntax error is because you didn't use a dash, but an endash or something. Remove the "–" chars and replace them with "-" chars

Comment: `for (A; B; C) { D }` is roughly `A; while (B) { D }  continue { C }`, which is roughly `A; while (B) { D; C }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've simplified your example just a little bit, discarded the useless junk and comments. Hope now it is clear what's going on:

```
print "Please enter a string: ";
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>);
print "Please enter a substring: ";
chomp(my $sub = <STDIN>);

my @places;

for (my $pos = -1; -1 != ($pos = index $string, $sub, $pos+1); push @places, $pos)
{
#do nothing here
}

print "Locations of '$sub' in '$string' were: @places\n";
```

The compilation error was due to '–' instead of '-';
The inner loop was in fact a string literal (useless) plus comments (useless), the extra braces are useless as well.

Comment: Thank you sir; now I understand it. Could you please explain why a + sign before a variable name is insignificant? Is it simply because you're just adding nothing?

Comment: The unary plus is sometimes used to tweak the syntax and guide the parser, it is basically a no-op from the functional point of view.

Comment: @A. Raj, Unary `+` doesn't perform addition. It literally does nothing. It's used to disambiguate syntax. For example, `{` can start an expression (hash constructor), and it can start a block. If Perl guesses wrong, you can tell it which one you want. `+{ ... }` will force the curly to be interpreted as an expression (since an expression must follow `+`), and thus as a hash constructor. `{; ... }` will be interpreted as a block (since Perl will lookahead one token and `;` can be in a hash constructor).